# Intersecting a degenerate line

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

I was looking at a solution with complex numbers to the following problem.

In $\triangle ABC$ with incenter $I$, the incircle is tangent to $CA,AB$ at $E,F$. The reflection of $E,F$ across $I$ are $G,H$. Let $Q=GH\cap BC$, and let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$. Prove $IQ\perp IM$.

They claimed that $Q=DD\cap GH$ and proceeded to use the intersection of lines formula to get a complex number representation for the point $Q$. The rest of the solution worked perfectly and resulted in the perpendicular property stated in the problem.

How does this work? Because clearly the "degenerate line" $DD$ could be any line
through $D$. Am I understanding something wrong?

Also, here is the diagram:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that by $DD$ they meant the tangent line to the circle at $D$, which of course is just $BC$ and so we already know that $Q$ is the intersection of it and $GH$. But I am also guessing that they used the fact that it is tangent to the circle somehow in the their development.

Comment: Yes, I think your right, they meant the tangent line. Also, they set the incircle of $ABC$ as the unit circle (to simplify calculations). Then they applied the following formula:
If $A,B,C,D$ lie on the unit circle, then $AB\cap CD$ is given by $\frac{ab(c+d)-cd(a+b)}{ab-cd}$. I'm wondering why this works with a degenerate set of points. I guess it intuitively makes sense, since if you define points $A,B,C,D$ on the unit circle and let $C$ approach $D$, then $CD$ will be closer and closer to the tangent line. But I wonder if there is a more rigorous prove using the formula.

Comment: Something is wrong with that: $AB \cap CD = B$, so they would hardly have to go through all of that to calculate it when they already know $b$.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear above. I was explaining what the formula was for for general points on the unit circle $A,B,C,D$. However, in their solution, they applied the formula for $G,H,D,D$.

Comment: Actually, that is rigorous. If we choose a $D'$ on the circle, then apply the formula to $G, H, D, D'$. Now consider the result a function of $D'$. Geometrically, we see that the limit as $D'$ approaches $D$ exists and is the point $Q$, and the we see that the formula is continuous and defined at $d' = d$. Thus the formula must give the complex number for $Q$.